# Search word from json file in node js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

i had json file in that data is like this

```
   [{"wingnum":0,"name":"vatsal chauhan","email":"chauhanvatsal81@yahoo.com","city":"bhavnagar","address":"asdf"},
{"wingnum":0,"name":"hardik","email":"hardikdave@gmail.com","city":"GANDHINAGAR","address":"Gandhinagar"},
{"wingnum":0,"name":"kevin","email":"kevin@gmail.com","city":"GANDHINAGAR","address":"Gandhinagar"},
{"wingnum":0,"name":"rohit","email":"rohit@gmail.com","city":"GANDHINAGAR","address":"Gandhinagar"}]
```

I want to search only name using fs.readfile or by  any other option my code is shown below

```
exports.getdata = function(req,res,next){
console.log('reqobj',req.body.params.name);

fs.readFile('./server/api/Appartment/appartment.json', 'utf8',function          read(err, data) {

        /*obj = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(obj);*/
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        else{
            if (data === ""){

                console.log('data does not exsist');


            }
            else{
                console.log('exsist data getdata');
                var arrayobject = JSON.parse(data);

                console.log(arrayobject);
                return res.status(200).json(data);
                }
        }

        // res.end();      
});
};
```

this code gives all data but i want to just get name according to parameter passed 
like autocomplete

Comment: So if i sum up your problem : you can read your file and load it in an array. But you can't seek into the array to find a string. Hence your problem is how to find a string in an array. What is a duplicated subject

Comment: Technically speaking, he doesn't want to "find a string in an array"; I think he wants to find a property in an object in an array.

Comment: for example if i am pass parameter 'a' then it's return only name which contain character 'a'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you've parsed the JSON and have the object in a variable, pass the object and the name to be searched in this function :

```
var searchname=function(x, somename){
    for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (x[i]['name']==somename){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1; //This means no match found
}
```

For example, you can get the document containing the name you want by doing this in your code :

```
var index=searchname(arrayobject, req.body.params.name);
if (index!=-1){
    console.log(json[index]);
    // Or do something else with json[index]
}
```

Update: If you want to do a search within the object itself, and get all the names matching a criteria, here's how the function would change :

```
var searchname=function(x, somename){
    var result=[];
    for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (x[i]['name'].indexOf(somename)>-1){
            result.push(x[i]['name']);
        }
    }
    return result; //Array containing matched names. Returns empty array if no matches found.
}

console.log(searchname(arrayobject, req.body.params.name)); //To display the working of above for testing.
```

Comment: your answer is right but i want to get only name which contain parameter value from .json file not entire array object

Comment: for example if i am pass parameter 'a' then it's return only name which contain character 'a'

Comment: Ah, I've updated my answer and added a section that has what you want. I guess I misunderstood earlier.
Please mark my answer as accepted if it solves your problem.